# How can I -abort ./bitcoind -reindex-chainstate?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, bitcoin-cli, reindex, cli

I made files re-accessible. Now we could return to a later, already synchronized state with the files. I tried to put `./bitcoind -reindex-chainstate=0`, also in a bitcoin.conf, also directly calling the conf. It goes on reindexing the chainstate.

Answer (score 1):

`-reindex-chainstate` is an instant operation: it wipes a the chainstate (UTXO) database. It is performed at startup whenever the `-reindex-chainstate` command-line option, or the `reindex-chainstate=1` config file parameter is provided. It cannot be interrupted, but it is so fast this is rarely a concern. It's equivalent to emptying the `chainstate/` directory by hand, FWIW.

Whenever the chainstate is behind the blockchain (i.e., you have blocks in your `blocks/` directory which haven't been processed yet), the missing blocks will automatically be processed. This will typically happen after a `-reindex` or `-reindex-chainstate`, but it can happen outside of those too. E.g. when you wipe the `chainstate/` directory yourself, or maybe if restore it to an older backup without making the equivalent restoration of the `blocks/` directory.

The naming of these options is somewhat confusing, because what they trigger isn't the actual reindexing, but just the wiping that preceeds it; the reindex is automatic, and progressive (it will continue where it left off if you shutdown and start again, unless you specify the reindex option again at startup; in that case, it is wiped again and you'll start over again).

FWIW, any option, including these, can be disabled using the "no" variant (`-noreindex-chainstate` here) or passing 0 (`-reindex-chainstate=0`). But, as explained, that just disables the wiping; it cannot undo a wipe, and thus cannot "abort" the reindexing, as Bitcoin Core cannot proceed without first processing all the blocks it has.

Answer (score -1):

In -help, -reindex-chainstate doesn't advertise to be an assignable [string typed] argument.

This means it is a boolean argument.

Don't assign it zero. Remove it completely.

Cheers!

---

Non assignable argument, boolean:

```
  -reindex-chainstate
       Rebuild chain state from the currently indexed blocks. When in pruning
       mode or if blocks on disk might be corrupted, use full -reindex
       instead.
```

Assignable argument, type string, not boolean:

```
  -settings=<file>
       Specify path to dynamic settings data file. Can be disabled with
       -nosettings. File is written at runtime and not meant to be
       edited by users (use bitcoin.conf instead for custom settings).
       Relative paths will be prefixed by datadir location. (default:
       settings.json)
```

Comment: removing lets it go on reindexing

Comment: let it reindex completely, then command it to close normally, let it finish normally; then try again and it shouldn't reindex

Comment: It does. Even after switching to ´-reindex´ and ´bitcoin-cli stop´.

Comment: It's impossible to abort reindexing, because it is an instant operation. Passing `-reindex` or `-reindex-chainstate` wipes certain parts of the database, at startup. The actual reindexing is what follows: the process of rebuilding the databases. Bitcoind cannot operate without those databases.

Comment: seems to be right description according to src/init.cpp "// This is a no-op if we cleared the coinsviewdb with -reindex or -reindex-chainstate". Post it as a main answer?
Dbs are supposed to be edited finely record by record, and this measure would have been of help.

Comment: This answer is also factually wrong; see my own answer.

Comment: @PieterWuille I just read, there is missing detail here, but I see nothing wrong.

Comment: You're saying that setting it to zero doesn't work; that's false. `-reindex-chainstate=0` is exactly the same as not setting it at all, and is the opposite from `-reindex-chainstate` or `-reindex-chainstate=1`.

Comment: Yeah, it is a boolean argument. If it is assignable is only because Bitcoin accidentally wrongly made boolean arguments assignable.